# options for TabBar/UITabBarController implementations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to xcode and trying to understand how UITabBarController works. I have been looking everywhere and could not find a straight solution to this question. In the majority of the examples/tutorials that I see, the UITabBarController is defined in the AppDelegate, and then once you launch the app, you see the tab bar right away. In my app, I want to show a welcome screen first, then once you click "Enter" you get to the tabbar view. So the ideal structure of my objects will be the following:

MyProjectAppDelegate --> MyProjectViewController --> FirstView / SecondView

As far as my understanding, nothing tabbar related should then be declared in MyProjectAppDelegate with this structure. I tried to look at some examples where the UITabBarController is declared in the AppDelegate and do the same in the MyProjectViewController, but nothing happens.

For example, I did this in my MyProjectViewController within an IBAction that is connected to the "Enter" UiButton on my welcome screen:

```
- (IBAction) EnterApp {

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

FirstView* first = [[FirstView alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];  

SecondView* second = [[SecondView alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *secondNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:firstNav,secondNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];    
}
```

Again, this did not do anything once I clicked on the "Enter" button, even though it does the job in the example where I took it from (where it's within the AppDelegate)

I also tried this on my MyProjectViewController, where the tabbar did show up on the First/Second view, but with no option to customize it (just blank black bars with nothing on them and no idea where to configure them):

```
- (IBAction) EnterApp {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];


self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

What went wrong here and what should be the right way to go about doing that? A quick example would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar in one of my apps. At first launch it shows a login screen. After the user successfully logs in, the app switches to a tab bar controlled view.

I do the switching in my appdelegate. The login view sends a notification which the app delegate observes and rebuilds the screen:

```
- (void)switchView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MyTabbarView *homeView = [[MyTabbarView alloc] init];
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:homeView];
    [mainNavController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
    mainNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    mainNavController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    [homeView release];
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using notifications, and changing my AppDelegate too much (I may have a few more tab bars later on and dont want to make a mess out of the app delegate - prefer a more modular design). thanks though!